# Polynomial Multiplication through Toom-Cook into Karatsubas

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to solve a polynomial multiplication problem recursively through using **Toom-Cook (Toom-3) once and Karatsuba (Toom-2) five times**, although I'm stuck after the first round of Karatsubas.

The base equations are:

```
P(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4 
Q(x)=5+4x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4
```

**Work so far:**

After padding with 0 to get n%3=0 I broke into 3 Karatsubas:

```
 K1     K2           K3
[1+2x] [3x^2+4x^3] [5x^4+0x^5]
[5+4x] [3x^2+2x^3] [1x^4+0x^5]
```

and yielded:

```
K1 => 5+14x+8x^2
K2 => 9+18x+8x^2
K3 => 5
```

After several awkward attempts, I'm not sure how to proceed from here, but I know I still have two more Karatsubas somewhere along the way. Or have I gone about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to be using Karatsuba within the computation of the Toom-Cook when you multiply the terms instead of trying to break up it beforehand.